# RestClient Upload to Amazon fails with InvalidArgument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, rest-client

I'm trying to upload an image via POST request to amazon:

```
    begin
      RestClient.post('http://public.domain.com/',
                      {
                        :transfer => {
                          :key => s3_key,
                          :acl => s3_acl,
                          :content_type => s3_content_type,
                          :AWSAccessKeyId => s3_AWSAccessKeyId,
                          :policy => s3_policy,
                          :signature => s3_signature
                        },
                        :upload => {
                          :file =>  File.new('/tmp/uup_1114.png', 'rb')
                        }
                      })
    rescue => e
      render :text => e.response
    end
```

In response I'm getting

```
InvalidArgument
POST requires exactly one file upload per request.
```

RubyOnRails, RestClient.

Comment: Looks like there was some error in arguments. Try to rewrite your code in some different manner.
Now I've got "Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'. If it is specified, please check the order of the fields".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331205/1035438, this may help you to solve your problem.